# freegeoip_net не работает, помогите привязатьNew SxGeo

Tags: php7

в общем когда то работал freegeoipDOTnet, при заходе на сайт определяло страну и выдавало на их языке контент, было так:

```html
<?php
require_once 'maincore.php';
require_once 'countries.php';
$tpl->assign("current","home");
$tpl->assign("title","Home");

$geo = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://freegeoip.net/json/".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']),true);
$geo['country_code'] = strtolower($geo['country_code']);
if($geo['country_code'] && $countries[$geo['country_code']]) {
  $country = $geo['country_code'];
  $cname = $countries[$geo['country_code']];
 } else {
  $country = 'us';
  $cname = "United States";
 }
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&regionCode=".strtoupper($country)."&maxResults=48&key=MyApiKey"),true); .........
```

Cейчас хочу подключить Sypex Geo Country (hххps://sypexgeo.net/ru/download/)

```html
<?php
require_once 'maincore.php';
require_once 'countries.php';
include("SxGeo.php");

$tpl->assign("current","trends");
$tpl->assign("title","Trends");

$SxGeo = new SxGeo('SxGeo.dat');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
var_export($SxGeo->getCountry($ip));

//Как далее передать страну в?

$geo['country_code'] = strtolower($geo['country_code']);
if($geo['country_code'] && $countries[$geo['country_code']]) {
  $country = $geo['country_code'];
  $cname = $countries[$geo['country_code']];
 } else {
  $country = 'us';
  $cname = "United States";
 }
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&regionCode=".strtoupper($country)."&maxResults=48&key=MyApiKey"),true); ........
```

Как сделать?

Answer (score 0):

вот так работает

```html
$SxGeo = new SxGeo('SxGeo.dat');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
var_export($SxGeo->getCountry($ip));

$geo_c = strtolower($SxGeo->getCountry($ip));
if($geo_c && $countries[$geo_c]) {
$country = $geo_c;
$cname = $countries[$geo_c];
} else {
$country = 'us';
$cname = "United States";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

только IP нужно более точнее определять

```
public function get_ip() {
  if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
    $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
      $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    return $ip;
    }
```